# Join table insert and update separately

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a registration form and 3 database table. Which is `users`, `security`,`activity`. In `user` there is `name`,`email` In `security` there is `token` and `tokenExpire` and in `activity` there is `ip`,`system`. 
I want to make insert file where if user submit form it fill that each tables as based places.

Let's consider,

`Name=$name | Email=$email | Ip=&ip | token=$token | tokenExpire= $time  | system=$system.`

I am insert connection like this :

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO users  (Name,Email) value('$name','$email'). system(token,tokenExpire)value('$token','$time).activity(ip,system)VALUE('$ip','$system' ");
```

Is this correct format?

Comment: Join table is tough to  understand 

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. 
Please try this, I hope it will help you

```
INSERT INTO users (Name, Email)
  VALUES('test', 'test');
INSERT INTO system (user_id,token, tokenExpire) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'token','tokenexpirevalue');
INSERT INTO activity (user_id,ip, system) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'ip','system');
```

Comment: But `ID` must be same for all users. To we can Fetch all details of single user in one page..How we can do that.

Comment: you mean user_id ?

Comment: Yes, your code might right because still I am not check that but what happen when I will fetch all details of one user want show at one page.. through your code all details send here and there how tables known this details is related to this user. Since let's make `ID` and unique and make it as userid.

Comment: Are you understand what I want say?

Comment: Actually I this is registration page where I am sending email verification token to user after verification token = null and expiretokens=null and update password =password . Hoe to make update connection